# Angular 4 array of ngModels - how to handle the name attribute

Tags: javascript, html, angular

Here's my class:

```
interface IHobby {
  name: string;
  type: string;
}

class User {
  constructor(public name: string, public hobbies: IHobby[]) { }
}
```

Now I'm trying to do a template form in Angular 4. I've noticed that in order to display the hobbies, I need to iterate through them. So, here's my HTML:

```
<div *ngFor="let h of user.hobbies; let i = index">
    #{{i}}<br />
  <input [(ngModel)]="h.name" name="hobby_name[{{i}}]" /> <br /><br />
  <input [(ngModel)]="h.type" name="type[{{i}}]" />
    <br /><br />
  <button class="btn btn-warn" (click)="remove(i)">Remove</button>
    <br /><br />
</div>
```

While this works, I'm not quite sure if:

1. I'm doing this the correct Angular 4 way - should I use `ngModel` for each item in the array?
2. Is it OK to define names as `name="hobby_name[{{i}}]"`? Because `name="hobby_name_{{i}}"` works as well. What is the correct, HTML5 and Angular 4 way?

Here's a working sample: https://plnkr.co/edit/chOsfhBThD3dA9FFqNPX?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to use name attribute since you're binding the inputs directly to the model. If you want to see instant changes in your model, you can keep using [(ngModel)], but if you want to update your model on form submit only, then you should not use ngModel. I would do a reactive form like this:

```
<div [formGroup]="form">
    <div formArrayName="hobbiesFormArray">
        <div *ngFor="let h of user.hobbies; let i = index" [formGroupName]="i">
            #{{i}}<br />
          <input formControlName="name" /> <br /><br />
          <input formControlName="type" />
            <br /><br />
          <button class="btn btn-warn" (click)="remove(i)">Remove</button>
            <br /><br />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And then in your component I would do something like:

```
form: FormGroup;

constructor(fb: FormBuilder) {
this.form = this.fb.group({
      name: '',
      hobbies: this.fb.array([])
    });
}

ngOnChanges() {
    this.form.reset({
      name: this.user.name
    });
    this.setHobbies(this.user.hobbies);
}

get hobbiesFormArray(): FormArray {
    return this.form.get('hobbiesFormArray') as FormArray;
};

setHobbies(hobbies: IHobby[]) {
    const hobbiesFormArray = this.fb.array(hobbies.map(hobby => this.fb.group(hobby)));
    this.form.setControl('hobbiesFormArray', this.fb.array());
}
```

Then in your onSubmit method I would convert the form model back to the user object:

```
const formModel = this.form.value;

const newHobbies: IHobby[] = formModel.hobbiesFormArray
                        .map(() => (hobby: IHobby) => Object.assign({}, hobby))

const newUser: User = {
  name: formModel.name as string,
  hobbies: newHobbies
};
```

And save newUser object with whatever means you have.

Comment: Thanks for your input. However, I already know how to handle this in reactive forms, I'm trying to learn the same with template forms. By removing the `name` attribute as you suggested, I get the following error: `If ngModel is used within a form tag, either the name attribute must be set or the form control must be defined as 'standalone' in ngModelOptions.`